# Android XML FrameLayout and BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, xml, android-framelayout, bottomnavigationview

How can I make the FrameLayout end with the beginning of the BottomNavigationView? The content of the FrameLayout is being overlapped by the navigation view.

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="...">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <FrameLayout
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView            
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/action_admin_bottom_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 17):

In case you want to keep using constraintlayout, you may add the following attributes to the framelayout in the xml:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Comment: @Mantas Laurinavičius is right. Don't forget to set `layout_height` to be 0dp

Answer (score 6):

This one worked for me. (Inspired by jackycflau)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="eu.ibsdevelopment.auto.mvp.view.main.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```